# Group occurences for duplicated entries in Excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula

[image]

I have a table with duplicated users from different domains. I want to have in a specific cell all the domains a specific user is part of.

Researching and trying to see how I could achieve that, I found TEXTJOIN and IF as a possible option, but for some reason, it is not working as expected. Instead of show only the tied domains, the formula shows all of them and checking how it works it seems like that would be the result it would return.

I wonder if you know what I am missing here?

As you will be able to see in the screenshot, for admin it shows the whole array of results and for operator, it shows nothing. Not sure why it behaves like that.

As expected outcome, considering the attached screenshot I would expect to see in cell F2 only the domains the account admin is part of, so just "aaa". For operator, "ccc".

Appreciate the support in advance.

Comment: Can you please [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/57066160/edit) to provide us with the expected outcome?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should be an array formula. Enter with <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Shift</kbd>+<kbd>Enter</kbd>.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

try this macro

```
Option Explicit
Sub Give_data()
Dim Dict As Object
Dim first As Worksheet
Dim Itm, K, i%: i = 2

 Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 Set first = Sheets("Sheet1")
 first.Range("E2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents
 Do Until first.Range("A" & i) = vbNullString
  K = first.Range("A" & i): Itm = first.Range("B" & i)
     If Not Dict.Exists(K) Then
       Dict.Add K, Itm
       Else
        Dict(K) = Dict(K) & ";" & Itm
      End If
    i = i + 1
  Loop
  With first.Range("E2").Resize(Dict.Count)
    .Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)
    .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Items)
  End With
  Dict.RemoveAll: Set Dict = Nothing
  first.Columns("E:F").AutoFit

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

For list all items to the admin,This macro can You Help

Sub My_data()

```
Dim Dict As Object
Dim first As Worksheet
Dim Itm, K, i%: i = 2
Dim My_String$
 Set Dict = CreateObject("Scripting.Dictionary")
 Set first = Sheets("Sheet1")

 With first
      .Range("E2").CurrentRegion.Offset(1).Resize(, 2).ClearContents
      .Range("E2") = .Range("A2")
     '===============================
     Do Until .Range("B" & i) = vbNullString
      My_String = My_String & ";" & .Range("B" & i)
       i = i + 1
     Loop
       .Range("F2") = Mid(My_String, 2, Len(My_String) - 1)
     '============================
     i = 3
    Do Until .Range("A" & i) = vbNullString
     If .Range("A" & i) = .Range("A2") Then GoTo Next_I
     K = .Range("A" & i): Itm = .Range("B" & i)
        If Not Dict.Exists(K) Then
          Dict.Add K, Itm
          Else
           Dict(K) = Dict(K) & ";" & Itm
         End If
Next_I:
       i = i + 1
     Loop
       With .Range("E3").Resize(Dict.Count)
           .Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Keys)
           .Offset(, 1).Value = Application.Transpose(Dict.Items)
       End With
  End With
  Dict.RemoveAll: Set Dict = Nothing
  first.Columns("E:F").AutoFit

End Sub
```